# Number of onto functions with a condition

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Let
A=
{
x
1
,
x
2
,
x
3
,
x
4
,
x
5
,
x
6
,
x
7
,
x
8
}
,
B=
{
y
1
,
y
2
,
y
3
,
y
4
}
.
The total number of function
f
:
A
→
B
that are onto and there are exactly three elements x in A such that
f
(
x
)=
y1
is?

Comment: Pick the three elements that map to $y_1$.  Then, pick an onto function from the remaining elements of $A$ to the remaining elements of $B$.  Apply rule of product and conclude.